# Can standardisation of predictors make SVM regression perform worse?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

- Standardisation = scaling so that mean of distribution is zero and variance equal to one.
- Are there any circumstances when applying standardisation to predictors would result to considerably worse (signal to noise ratio) performance of SVM (Support Vector Machine) regression?

Comment: Consider posting at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Gabriel Romon Have considered it before posting. But would like to keep it in math.stackexchange.com because there are tags associated with it (p.s. there are several threads across SE on where ML questions should go with no definite conclusions).